# Issue with buildozer VM

Tags: android, python-3.x, compiler-errors, kivy, buildozer

I have been fumbling with buildover for 3 days trying to get it to work. (to android) I have been all over the internet and I have tried using both vm's listed on github.com/kivy/buildozer (the reference at the top and the one at the bottom) using the instructions as provided on the site and in the readmes.

Steps I take after I open the vm:

1) Download my python file to /home/user/Desktop/whateveriwant

2) Rename the main (only) python file to 'main.py'

3) 'cd /home/user/Desktop/whateveriwant'

4) 'buildover init'

5) in buildover.spec:'requirements=hostpython,kivy','log_level=2'

6) 'buildover android_new debug'

I'm running native Ubuntu 18 64 bit (on a 64 bit processor) and I've reinstalled the entire OS atleast 4 times now, trying different methods such as crystax and python3 and changing cython to version 0.25.2

I am confused, however, because i wrote my code in python 3 ('from kivy.uix.label import Label', etc.) and I see many options for running buildozer "with" python3.

I don't know if running it "with" python3 is necessary because I wrote my app in python 3 or if it has to do with the sdk and other dependencies and compatibility requirements that don't apply to me.

It's not letting me post the error output on here.

Here's the error output:

https://pastebin.com/e38Bv4Gi

```
code
```

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled and did exactly as above and it worked. I must have messed up somewhere. I am new to SE. What do I do from here?